# Django orm. Nested tables

Tags: django, nested

I need to create table like this:

**Event Table**

```
id  Event       
 1  event A ->
                Time     Param 1   Param 2  ..
                 44        12.5      145
                 45        14.5      148
                 46        13.5      138
 2  event B ->
                Time     Param 1   Param 2 ..
                 44        12.5      145
                 45        14.5      148
                 46        13.5      138
 3  event C - > 
                And so on...
 ..
```

How can I do this with Django ORM?
(Use SQLite)

Answer (score 0):

You mean how to make django model like so?

here's sample model code.

```
    from django.db import models


    class Event(models.Model):
            time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
            param_1 = models.FloatField()
            param_2 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

After, you should makemigration & migrate

```
$python manage.py makemigrations
$python manage.py migrate
```

**Update

You mean you want to make two model - `Event` and `EventTime`, right?

Here's new two model.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        # have to set max_length you want
        max_length=255,
    )

class EventTime(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(
        Event,
        # in django==2.0, you should write on_delete option
        on_delete=CASCADE,
    )
    time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    param_1 = models.FloatField()
    param_2 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Don't worry about `Event` model's ID. django ORM automatically creates id.

If you want more info about `ForeignKey` and `on_delete` option, check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) (django official document)

Comment: Thank you, but events must be in table too. Main table with name events and events ID, sub table with params on every events.

Comment: Oh I misunderstand your question. I will update answer